# Error while creating Identity matrix using list in python

Tags: python, list, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I was trying to make an identity matrix to find the inverse. But I am stuck at this moment due to a bug in the code. A fresh eye would help a lot.

```
identity=[]
null=[]
for i in range(3):
    null.append(i*0)
for j in range(3):
    identity.append(null)
for k in range(3):
    identity[k][k]=1

print(identity)
```

The result I got

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

what I desired for

```
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on @enke Answer, you can do it in modular form, creating an identity matrix of as many rows as you want.

```
def eye(num):
    mat = []
    for i in range(num+1):
        row = [0]*(num+1)
        row[i]=1
        mat.append(row)
    return mat
```

Now you can easily do

```py
eye(5)

Out[2]: 
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: thank you but what is the implication of a square bracketed zero, in the code.
can you formulate a simpler code. something a noob can follow.

Comment: In Python `[0]*3` will be equal to `[0,0,0]` and `[0]*4` will be equal to `[0,0,0,0]` so we create a row with all zeros. and then change the value of the current row index in that row to one. so if it is the 3rd row, it will change the 3rd value to 1 and the rest will be 0.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that `identity` doesn't have 3 different `null` lists, it has 3 of the exact same `null` list. That's why in each iteration, you change value of all of them.

For example, you'll find that instead of the last for loop, if you simply run the following code:

```
identity[1][1]=1
print(identity)
```

you'll find that the outcome is

```
[[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
```

If you want to create an identity matrix with list, you can do the following: in each `i`th iteration, you append a row where the `i`th element is 1:

```
identity = []
for i in range(3):
    row = [0]*3
    row[i] = 1
    identity.append(row)
```

As a function:

```
def eye(size):
    identity = []
    for i in range(size+1):
        row = [0]*(size+1)
        row[i] = 1
        identity.append(row)
    return identity

eye(3)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the explanation and the code, it helped.
But i had never seen what [0] *i meant. can I get any documentation concerning the conceptual understanding of the code. Though its obvious  [0]*3 = [0,0,0]
I'm blind ti its inner mechanism. thanks anyways.

Comment: @Charles you can read the python docs on it [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/multiple_concatenation.html)

Answer (score 1):

```py
identity = [[int(j == i) for j in range(n_rows)] for i in range(n_rows)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but..

The point is that when you run the second loop (`for j in range(3):`) you are appending three times the object called `null`.

When you run the third loop `for k in range(3):` you are accessing and modifying the same object each time.

You can check what I mean printing the [object id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id):

```
for k in range(3):
    print(id(identity[k]))
```

The solution is just to append a [copy of the object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#module-copy), changing the second loop into:

```
for j in range(3):
    identity.append(null.copy()) # <-- added .copy()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Happy to have your back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Numpy Library to create easily

```
import numpy as np 
data = np.eye(rows, columns) 
[![# Let's do that: 
data = np.eye(5,5) 
print(data)][1]][1]
```

Hope you understood!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmKpe.png

Comment: thank you, but can you give a solution without numpy.
i've edited the codes again.

Comment: Its numpy eye not eyes

Comment: yes, it eye sorry

Answer (score 0):

a = int(input('enter the Number of matrix you need:: '))

```
lis = []


for i in range(a):
    new = [0]*a
    new[i] = 1
    lis.append(new)

# Now you can add many identity matrix, Enjoy!
```